# Is there a Stack Exchange site for cars, e.g. finding what is horse power etc

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking to buy a car and do not know what some jargon means, like what to look for e.g. MPG or BHP, so I was wondering if there was a stack that can answer my question pre-buying.

Answer (score 5):

[Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) has some questions about the meaning of technical terms related to cars, like [BHP](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25231/what-actually-is-brake-horsepower-bhp).

"What to look for" sounds like an unclear question, since it will depend on a lot of things (e.g. your budget and your location). The site does have some questions about [buying](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buying) a car, but a lot of them are closed (there have probably been more questions, but they might be [deleted](/help/roomba) after a year).

Comment: "What to look for", to define it more. People talk about MPG or BHP, I did see vidoes on HP but totally clueless and same for MPG, things that matter i.e. If a person who knows cars with me or a sales person who is selling me, would win coz I have no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: Relevant, from Mechanics Meta: [Can I ask how to learn what car to buy question here?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1379)